# JavaScript Validator keeps saying Unexpected 'if' regarding line 11, and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

When I use http://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate to validate the code below, it keeps saying line 11

```
if ($('#s4-bodyContainer').hasScrollBar().horizontal) {
```

is -- Unexpected 'if' -- and I can't figure out how to fix it.  Here is the complete code.  I am putting it at the bottom of a SharePoint master page to fix an issue with wide tables appearing on certain screens expanding past the branding header and footer.  What this code is supposed to do is detect if there is a horizontal scrollbar in the browser window.  If so, then it is adding some classes to a few div tags that fixes the issue.

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
      var e = this.get(0);
      return {
        horizontal: e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth
      };
    }
    if ($('#s4-bodyContainer').hasScrollBar().horizontal) {
      // has scrollbar so add some classes
      ($("#s4-bodyContainer").addClass("ecs-absolute"));
      ($("#s4-workspace").addClass("ecs-relative"));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you AnilRedshift!  Your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a semicolon `;` after the definition of `hasScrollBar`. You also have mismatched braces around the outer function. This works for me:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function () {
        var e = this.get(0);
        return {
            horizontal: e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth
        };
    }; // <-- added a semicolon here
    if ($('#s4-bodyContainer').hasScrollBar().horizontal) {
        // has scrollbar so add some classes
        ($("#s4-bodyContainer").addClass("ecs-absolute"));
        ($("#s4-workspace").addClass("ecs-relative"));
    }
})(); // <-- fixed up your IIFE here
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped with this.  AnilRedshift's answer worked for me with one small change.  The last line had to be changed from: })(); // <-- fixed up your IIFE here to }()); // <-- fixed up your IIFE here -- now is passed both JSlint and Code Beautify.

Answer (score 0):

You do have one syntax error. You shouldn't have `);` after your `if`. You probably intend to have this:

```
if ($('#s4-bodyContainer').hasScrollBar().horizontal) {
    // has scrollbar so add some classes
    ($("#s4-bodyContainer").addClass("ecs-absolute"));
    ($("#s4-workspace").addClass("ecs-relative"));
  }
}); // <-- Closes off the IIFE
```

But you probably also want to invoke that IIFE so change the last line to:

```
})(jQuery); // <--- Closes off IIFE
```

After fixing that, [your code is completely valid.](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)

Comment: That tool is missing some things about `use strict` mode. For example, it doesn't seem to catch variables being used out of scope, nor does it catch missing semicolons

Comment: @AnilRedshift That tool is only for ensuring it's syntactically valid. Nothing more. Strict mode doesn't affect the syntax and missing semicolons are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon after the function assignment:

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
  var e = this.get(0);
  return {
    horizontal: e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth
  };
}; // <<<<< here!
```

The closure of the self-executing function should be fine.  I prefer this form:

```
fn = ( function () { ... }( jQuery ) );
```

This passes jslint.  I suggest you use that instead of an online validator.

```
$ sudo npm install -g jslint
```